# Why do I get this error message from LowpassFilter?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I have a list of numbers *data* of length 10^7.
I have values

```
rate = 100000.;
cutoff = 2000.;
```

I try to low pass filter with

```
LowpassFilter[data
, Quantity[cutoff, "Hz"]
, SampleRate -> Quantity[rate, "Hz"]]
```

I get the error message:

```
LowpassFilter::srate: The value of sample rate should be a positive machine-sized integer number or a Quantity representing frequency instead of $Failed.
```

But if I replace *rate* with its value, it works fine.

```
LowpassFilter[data, Quantity[cutoff, "Hz"], 
 SampleRate -> Quantity[100000., "Hz"]]
```

Why is that, and is there a workaround?

Comment: The help file says the rate needs to be an integer. Your rate 100000. is a real number. Use an integer 100000

Comment: Your first version works for me on Mathematica 12.3.  Are you on an earlier version?

Comment: What help file is that? The error message says "The value of sample rate should be a positive machine-sized integer number or a Quantity representing frequency" Mine is the latter. Note also that LowpassFilter does not complain when you use a real number in the quantity. See my second example.

Comment: I am on 12.3 for Mac OS.

Comment: The first version works for me on 12.2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

No answer to why, but found a work-around. Round the rate value.

```
LowpassFilter[data, Quantity[cutoff, "Hz"], 
 SampleRate -> Quantity[Round[rate], "Hz"]]
```